Limit the options available for recording screen
I am working on a screen recorder application and wanted to see if it's possible to limit what options the user can pick to record?
Right now, I am calling navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({}) which prompts the user to share either 1) Entire Screen, 2) Application Window or 3) Chrome Tab
However, I would like to remove the option to select chrome tab, I just want the user's to seeEntire screen or application window choices.
I thought the solution was to set the displaySurface: window value:
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
      video: {
        width: 9999999999,
        height: 9999999999,
        dispkaySurface:"window,
      },
    });

However, I am still being presented with the three options instead of just the tab. Does anyone know how I can limit which screens can be shared?
Thank you in advance!

Take a look at the selfbrowsersurface: "exclude" option. Not sure whether this just prevents the current tab from being available though

thanks for this @phuzi , i tried it out it is just for limiting current tab option in the list of tabs but i want to limit the entire option to choose tabs, i want that user should be able to see only 2 options choose window or choose entire screen
